# Which BP's offer snapshots for v1.4? --mongodb-wipe?

Tags: block-producer, blockchains, database

Which BP's or websites offer snapshots for v1.4 ?

Is --mongodb-wipe still required for replaying?

Comment: I also want to know where is the snapshot

Answer (score 1):

The EOS Node Tools website provides daily block archives. It works with eosio v1.4.1.

https://eosnode.tools/blocks

As far as I tested, `--mongodb-wipe` is not required but recommended. If you did not wipe the db, duplicate documents will be inserted.